# SIMPLE HTML DOM - how to ignore nested elements?

Tags: php, dom, simple-html-dom

My html code is as follows

```
<span class="phone">
i want this text
<span class="ignore-this-one">01234567890</span>
<span class="ignore-this-two" >01234567890</span>
<a class="also-ignore-me">some text</a>
</span>
```

What I want to do is extract the 'i want this text' leaving all of the other elements behind. I've tried several iterations of the following, but none return the text I need:

```
$name = trim($page->find('span[class!=ignore^] a[class!=also^] span[class=phone]',0)->innertext);
```

Some guidance would be appreciated as the simple_html_dom section on filters is quite bare.

Comment: Well, if you can always guarantee that the `i want this text` will be the first child, then just select the first child of the `span.phone` element. If there is more to this decision, then please explain.

Comment: selecting span.phone->plaintext also returns the plaintext of every element underneath it. Also there may be occasions where the 'i want this text' is not present in which case it should return empty.

Comment: If I read the intention of your *find* query right you misunderstand the XML Tree and how the DOM represents it. In Xpath what you're looking for is `//span[@class="phone"]/text()` - I'm not fluent with simple-html-dom, but what you could do is getting the span's innerHTML and then create a new DOM outof it and remove all child element nodes so the text is preserved and isolated.

Answer (score 1):

what about using php preg_match (http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

try the below:

```
<?php

$html = <<<EOF
<span class="phone">
i want this text
<span class="ignore-this-one">01234567890</span>
<span class="ignore-this-two" >01234567890</span>
<a class="also-ignore-me">some text</a>
</span>;
EOF;

$result = preg_match('#class="phone".*\n(.*)#', $html, $matches);

echo $matches[1];

?>
```

regex explained:
find text *class="phone"* then proceed until the end of the line, matching any character using *.**. Then switch to a new line with *\n* and grab everything on that line by enclosing *.** into brackets.

The returned result is stored in the array $matches. $matches[0] holds the value that is returned from the whole regex, while $matches[1] holds the value that is return by the closing brackets.